# Facebook event plugin in react.js disappears after click to another page link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, facebook-sdk-4.x

I've been trying to get the Facebook event plugin to work in my create-react-app and can't figure it out.

In my Events.js file I added this:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div className="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/[artistname]" data-tabs="events"
data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true"
data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
  <div className="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/[artistname]/events">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/[artistname]/events" target="_blank">[artistname] - coming events</a>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

The SDK is imported in index.html

Everything works fine when I load the actual events page, but after clicking on "Start" and going back to "Events" the plugin disappears.
Some say to put

```js
componentDidMount(){
  window.FB.XFBML.parse()};
}
```

in the component, but my Event.js is a function.

I'm running out of google links now, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What Facebook event plugin are you talking about? [This one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/v4.0#event-handling)? Also I notice you are tagging [facebook-sdk-4.x] which is outdated

Comment: I'm using this plugin from their developers website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/
I don't believe my issue is connected to an outdated version of the sdk

Comment: Sorry I might be confusing you with event handlers and my actual page being called Events.js
To clarify - Events.js is only a page with information about coming events for my artist profile

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to use the iframe option, but that doesn't directly answer your question.

## Answer 1: use the `useEffect` hook

#### [Example CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-davinci-vv5z0)

Instead of using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method from class components, you can use the `useEffect` hook:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    window.FB.XFBML.parse();
  }, []);
```

This will call `window.FB.XFBML.parse` once per render.

Note: You may want to wrap that with an `if (window.FB)` to catch instances where `window.FB` didn't load

## Answer 2: Convert to class component

You can of course convert your component to the old class based style:

```
export default class Events {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.FB.XFBML.parse();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* ... */}

        <div
          className="fb-page"
          data-href={`https://www.facebook.com/${artistName}`}
          data-tabs="events"
          data-width=""
          data-height=""
          data-small-header="true"
          data-adapt-container-width="true"
          data-hide-cover="false"
          data-show-facepile="true"
        >
          <div className="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            <blockquote cite={`https://www.facebook.com/${artistName}/events`}>
              <a
                href={`https://www.facebook.com/${artistName}/events`}
                target="_blank"
              >
                {artistName} - coming events
              </a>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually used the npm react-facebook to get it to work without any complications. But I will try your solution just in case, I don't like to rely on react-facebook it if it stops working for some reason